# Разделение строчки на массив с разделителем TAB

Tags: javascript, массивы

Мне в форму закидывают цифры через табуляцию:

```
4   5   4   4   3   2   3
```

Мне их нужно разбить в массив, для этого я использую `.split("  ");` Но когда внутри tab, то он строчку разбивает не правильно.

Как разбить строку в массив если в ней разделители - табы?

Comment: Вам ответ, который дал @Darth подошел? Если да, то поставьте отметку что приняли. Если нет, ну тогда остается открытым...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь регуляркой:

```js
console.log(`4   5   4   4   3   2   3`.split(/\s+/g))
```